# Castor XML Mapping: How to map to different XML fields using the same Java Class

Tags: java, xml, castor

Is that possible to make a mapping to map to different xml fields using the same Java Class?  For example, I have a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private String address;
}
```

However, I have two xmls for Person, but their "address" in xml has different tag names:

```
  xml 1:
 <name>xxxx</name>
 <address> xxxxxx </address>

  xml 2:
  <name>xxxx</name>
  <addr> xxxxxx </addr>
```

So in this case, I can define two Person classes with different "address" fields, but is there a way to use the same mapping for both "address" and "addr"? thanks.

```
    <class name="Person">   
         <map-to xml="person" />
         <field name="name" type="string">
           <bind-xml name="name" node="element"/>
         </field>
         <field name="address" type="string">
           <bind-xml name="address" node="element"/>  // and also "addr"??
         </field>
```